# Fetch XML vs SQL CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I am having a bizarre problem, and was hoping that someone could shed some light on why it is occurring.  If I Query dynamics using FetchXML using the following:

```xml
<fetch mapping="logical" count="10" distinct="true" version="1.0">
<entity name="activitypointer">
    <attribute name="activityid" />
    <attribute name="activitytypecode" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="statecode" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="actualend" />
    <order attribute="actualend" descending="true" />
    <filter type="or">
        <condition attribute="regardingobjectid" operator="eq" value="66431c2f-fab6-dd11-94f2-0014221f6f5c" />
    </filter>
</entity>
```

Then I get the following set of results:

[image: Blurred 1]

However if I do the same query in SQL:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 activityid, activitytypecodename, createdon, owneridname, statecodename, statuscodename, subject, actualend FROM [CRM2011_MSCRM].[dbo].[FilteredActivityPointer] WHERE regardingobjectid = '66431C2F-FAB6-DD11-94F2-0014221F6F5C' ORDER BY actualend DESC
```

Then I get the following results:

[image: Blurred 2]

You can see that the results are pretty much the same, however if you look at the status code column then you can see that the results differ in the fact that one states that it has been sent while the other has been completed.

Therefore how can I filter based upon the status of the item when the two different methods seem to bring back different results for the state code?

(I am currently trying to do a report in SSRS using FetchXML I have previously tried doing it in SQL but had problems, therefore used FetchXML to solve this)

**-- Edit**

When I use the appointment entity then I do get the correct results:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" count="50" version="1.0">
<entity name="appointment">
    <attribute name="activityid" />
    <attribute name="activitytypecode" />
    <attribute name="actualend" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="statecode" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <filter>
        <condition attribute="regardingobjectid" operator="eq" value="66431c2f-fab6-dd11-94f2-0014221f6f5c" />
    </filter>
</entity>
```

Which returns this:

[image: Appointment only query]

The only problem with this though is I need to know the status for a whole list of different activities - thus I thought you needed to use the activity pointer (as it is the base class plus you can't join results together in SSRS.)

Comment: which one show the correct results?

Comment: The SQL shows the correct result. - I don't believe you can complete an email and have it as a cancelled status.

Comment: can you try to run a fetchxml only against `appointment` to check if statuscode is retrieved correctly?

Comment: I agree the SQL looks correct - the FetchXml returns a Task with no statuscode which is clearly bogus.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this isn't an answer on how to solve this, perhaps, but I think I can shed some light on why it may be happening.
For the statuscode of an activitypointer, fetchXML is taking the integer value and mapping it to the activitypointer lookup table, while SQL maps it to the actual child entity's table.

For example, take your very first record, which happens to be an email. FetchXML says the status is "cancelled". Checking the activitypointer metadata (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328148.aspx) we see that "cancelled" is value "3". Now, going to the email entity metadata (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh155312.aspx) we see that value "3" is actually "sent", which is what SQL says.

This goes for all the entities you have in the table. The lonely Task with no fetchXML status, for example, is actually completed according to sql. That's value "5" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594424.aspx), which doesn't map to anything for activitypointers; their values are limited to a range of 1-4. As a result, fetchXML shows nothing.

Try getting the statuscodeValue rather than name. I expect the integer values will be identical for both fetchXML and SQL. Why they map the names differently I can't answer.